# Active Fast-Flux Domains

Tags: data-request

I am looking for fast-flux domains that are currently active so I can train a model that I build. I found this so far: https://atlas.arbor.net/summary/fastflux but it is outdated.

Comment: After learning what "fast flux" means, I think it is rather natural that any information on currently active fast flux networks is outdated really soon. And, it does not seem to fit the concept of "Open Data" well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not fit to the concept of (persistent) Open Data.

Comment: @jknappen, please could you say more about why you feel the question doesn't fit the concept of 'open data'? Is it not enough for the service that provides the data to be persistent?

Comment: @tomp: A persistent service providing non-persistent data is worth nothing when it comes to reproducible research. The data themselves needs to be open and persistent.

Comment: Also, there are papers out there where such data sets were used for training purposes. In addition, when atlas (site I mention above) released that list, all domains were active. The "outdated really soon" is at the very least subjective.

Comment: @jknappen I agree with your reproducibility point, but the systems for making dynamic data persistently citable are not yet well established, so making persistence a requirement for 'open data' in this context sets a high bar.

Comment: I just found this which could be of help: http://www.secrepo.com/ , but still no fast-flux ones.

Comment: @jknappen where is the concept of (persistent) Open Data defined? I've never heard of it before. Data can always be remixed or reused. I'm not a fan of dismissing any openness or open data related question.

Comment: Even if persistence was an issue, the features extracted (given that domains are still active so they can be resolved) from such a data set will be reproducible.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that the various RBLs were set up ([Realtime Blackhole Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL)) ... some of them keep info about *why* they added a specific host, but I don't know which ones allow global dumps.  (most just do lookups, so you can query in real time against an incoming SMTP connection)